# Pincode to check shipping serviceability in the product page magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, shipping, products-management

Is there any extension or way to implement the  pincode(zipcode) to check shipping serviceability in product page because most of the courier services not  giving service to all the areas, So customer can check service availability to their area at product page itself,

Comment: This is the website of the company which specializes in shipping-related Magento extensions: http://www.webshopapps.com/eu/extensions, I don't know if they have something like this but you might want to check there.

Comment: Did my answer help you? Can I provide any further direction for you?

Comment: Kindly help me to add an extension for a pin code service availability in magento 1.9. I tried it but failed. Please checkout the website [flowerportal](https://flowerportal.in)

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not familiar with what a 'pincode' is, there is a shipping estimator widget on the shopping cart page that should return any availability messages/rates from all available shipping methods. To accomplish what you ask, you can add it to the product page.

**Do it yourself:**

In your local.xml layout file, add this declaration:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="checkout/cart_shipping" name="catalog.product.shipping" as="shipping_estimator" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

In the `catalog/product/view.phtml` template file:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping_estimator'); ?>
```

**Magento Connect extension:**

This extension is free and adds it to the right sidebar in two-column-right layout:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/estimate-shipping-on-the-product-page.html